# .NET 6 - Serialize data into JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I just face wall trying to create my.net API.
I'm trying to Serialize data from db view into JSON. I can't make it to the below form.

```
  { name : "Name",
       someObject : {
                    name : "Name2"}
```

Could I can serialize it from single db view to that form?
Or if no, how I can relate models and context created with `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold`

Hope You can help me ❤

Comment: try `Newtonsoft.json` then `string DataPack = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Data, Formatting.None);`

Comment: What does your object look like? The above is not valid json, by the way.

Comment: @PMF, Should looks like this:
"Products" : [
{"productID" : "someID",
 "stockLevels" : [
            {"warehouseID" : "someID",
             "availableStock"   : someNumber},
            {"warehouseID" : "someID", 
             "availableStock" : someNumber}
          ]}], 
"companyId": "someID"}

Comment: @PMF I don't have anything to show as an object. The case is that I'm not sure how I can model a single view into the needed form. DId its possible by serializing it or did I should create more views (single object-  single view) and then create a class that will have these objects as properties. I already tried both but without positive results.